# how to control API access to applications

Tags: api, security

I think there is no way to do this but wanted to check.

I would want to control what remote applications can access Salesforce via the API.
Right now, if you set "API Enabled" to true, you are basically opening up access to your org to any api-based applications that your users would install.

You might not want to have this since you really don't know what these applications would do with your data. I would rather block access to all applications and then only open up the API for specific apps you want them to use.

Telling your users only to use application X and Y is one thing but having no way to block them from using other applications isn't a comforting feeling.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can whitelist applications, but you can audit usage retroactively. Under `Setup | Manage Apps | Connected Apps` and `Setup | Manage Apps | Connected Apps OAuth Usage` you will find a list of connected applications.

You can manage *Connected Apps* via profiles: see https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=connected_app_view_details.htm&language=en_US

For *OAuth*, you can get the number of users that have authorized it. If you click on the `User Count` you will get the user names and the ability to (temporarily) Revoke access.

I would recommend checking the OAuth list from time to time to verify which applications are being used; if you see something suspicious you would have a chance to investigate and educate your users as necessary.

Comment: On the plus side, salesforce.com's security works in the Administrator's favor, if it's configured correctly. Consider setting your data to private or public read-only to limit the damage that a user might be able to do, regardless of if the app is trusted or not. If John Doe wants to try out a `DELETE * FROM Account` query in a hypothetical SQL-to-SOAP app, he'll only delete his records, nobody else's (unless he's a manager...). Note that *Connected Apps* can be restricted by IP, Profile, etc. Only regular API apps, like the Apex Data Loader, are the ones you have to worry about.